# Fragment not Saving Instance State

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, orientation, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to save state data when you change the orientation of the android device, since I understand that's when it destroys activities and fragments.  Does something special have to be done for fragments that are inside of other layouts (I have two fragments inside of my main activity xml).  I thought I could simply handle saving data with saveInstanceState, but that seems to never be called, as the bundle that's passed into the onCreateView always is null.  Any thoughts?  I"m sure I'm missing something obvious here.

```
public class ControlFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


int hours, min, sec;
TextView text;
Button start;
Async async;
boolean clicked;

private static final String THREAD_STATUS = "thread status";
private static final String HOUR = "hour";
private static final String MINUTE = "minute";
private static final String SECOND = "second";

public ControlFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_control, container, false);
    text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    start = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        text.setText("Test");
        boolean isRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(THREAD_STATUS);
        if (isRunning) {
            sec = savedInstanceState.getInt(SECOND);
            text.setText("" + sec);
            async = new Async();

            async.execute(sec);
        }
    }
    else {
        async = new Async();
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (async.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        async = new Async();
        async.execute(0);
    }
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (async != null && async.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        outState.putBoolean(THREAD_STATUS, true);
        outState.putInt(SECOND, sec);

        async.cancel(true);
    }
    else {
        outState.putBoolean(THREAD_STATUS, false);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (async != null && async.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        async.cancel(true);
        async = null;
    }
}

private class Async extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        text.setText(values[0] + values[1] + values[2]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        sec = integers[0];
        while (sec < 100) {
            try {
                sec++;
                String second;
                if(sec > 59){
                    sec = 0;
                }

                if (sec < 10) {
                    second = "0" + sec;
                } else {
                    second = "" + sec;
                }

                publishProgress("" + sec, ":" + sec, ":" + second);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Code for Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

public Button nextScreen;
public TextView timer;
public ControlFrag control;
public ListFrag list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    control = new ControlFrag();
    list = new ListFrag();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       // transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, control, "portraitControl");
    }

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container1, list, "landscapeList");
    }
    else {
        nextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextScreen);
        nextScreen.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public  void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("Test", "GO");
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        nextScreen.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Test"));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}




@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("portraitControl") != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, list, "portraitList");
        transaction.commit();
    }
    else {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, control, "portraitControl");
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Try adding `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: @snowday313 Show us the code where you are saving the instance.

Comment: @Zohra Khan Doesn't onSaveInstanceState () above automatically get called when the device is turned, saving the state?

Comment: @Snowday313 please post the activity code..the activity which is hosting this fragment

Comment: @ZohraKhan Added Activity code.  In portrait mode, it holds one fragment at a time, and then in landscape, it has two separate fragment containers.